# facebook users who r not my friends but using the app

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

The new Facebook graph api has divided friends into `Friends` & `Invitable_friends` .

`me/friends/` returns my friends who are using the app while `me/invitable_friends/` returns only the list of my friends who are not using the app.

But in my app,a user may interact with random users too who may not be on his friend list.

So how do i get user data for those who are using the app but are not on my friend list.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get details of users who are using the app but are not your friends,call the following

> graph.facebook.com/v2.0/
>
> ?ids={comma-separated-ids}&access_token=app_access_token&fields=name,picture

access_token is a must else graph-api returns following error-

`The global ID xyz is not allowed. Please use the application specific ID instead.`

This will work for all users who have authenticated the app no matter their authentication date,but for any non-app user graph-api returns above error message.

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same issue and solved it like that: when a user starts your app by default you ask for permission to access his public profile information, which includes real ID, name and some other. You simply store the user data (id, name, etc.)in a database. This way you keep track of all the people using your app and they can interact with each other.

JavaScript Example:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB._https = true;
    console.log('here');
    FB.init({ appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', cookie: true, xfbml: true, oauth: true, version : 'v2.0'});
    Login();
};
function Login() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse){
            checkUser();
            } 
            else{
                console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            }
        }
    );
}
function checkUser() {
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "cgi-bin/checkUser.cgi",
        cache: false,
        data: {"user_name" : response.name, "u_id" : response.id, "link" : response.link},
        success: function() //onSuccess,
        { 
            console.log("user " + response.name + " checked!");
        },
        error: function()
        {
            console.log("Error with server connection on user checking");
        }
    }); 
});
}
```

I don't know in what language you are writing the app but I believe that in every language you should call the "login" function, which asks the user for permissions and basically gets access to info.

Comment: If your app was launched before v2.0, you can still use the v1.0 BUT this feature will be removed soon. Check the Edit on my answer, This JS code basically sends an AJAX request to a server script with the user info.

Comment: Your approach will not suit my purpose.Storing user FB profile details(like name,first name,picture,etc) in DB doesn't make any sense as any change user makes to his profile will not be reflected in DB.I need a solution where I can pass global ID of a user,to graph api v2.0,who is not my friend and yet gather his details like name,pic,etc.Thanks for your help anyways :)

Comment: If your app have the user's permission, you can just pass his ID to the graph api and view the info you have access to. And by saving info in DB I didn't mean saving his entire info, that is acessible through the FB api, I meant that if you want to keep track of the people using your app, you can simply save their ID in DB. Through the ID you can access everything you have permissions for throug the api.